# Can you make Windows 10 trigger a VBS script instead of playing a sound?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I want to make my computer use TTS to inform me of certain things like a critical error by speaking. I think it would be much cooler to hear "A critical error has occurred." instead of " *Musical beep that sounds like all other musical beeps* "

Obviously I could just make audio recordings of my computer's TTS and put those on as the windows sounds. Thing is I would rather use VBS scripts so that if there are ever other user accounts the TTS could tell people via their username things like "A critical error has occurred. Mike, restart your computer." as a means to help mitigate IT work I have to do in my home, and also to make things nicer for the less computer literate people. It would also mean if I ever change the voice that the recordings all change too.

If this isn't possible, oh well. If it is, I would love to know how.

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you. I'll just use audio recordings then.

Comment: If you do not care about performance you can use event-trigger scheme. Before playing audio file the system checks registry settings: what file should be played. Than the system read audio file. So you can **set audit** on apropriate registry key (or audio file). Then **create event-trigger task** to call VBScript. It's awfull and tricky way to solve your problem. But you can even automate event-trigger task creation (by VBscript).

Comment: @Daemon-5 I've settled on using wav files. Howeaver I am having a problem getting a vbs script to detect the general time of day (morning, noon, night) and playing an appropriate audio clip. The idea is the computer says "good morning" or whatever is appropriate as the startup sound. I did this a long time ago, but I can't work out how...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set speech = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")

Nom="Mike"

text = "A critical error has occurred."&Nom& " restart your computer."

speech.Speak text